# How to add image at the end of text line using pdfmake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfmake

I'm using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted). I'm trying to figure out how to add image to the end of text line instead of the new line. 
For example:

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        'Test text',
        {image: 'sampleImage.jpg', width: 24, height: 24}
    ]
}
```

Using this description pdfmake generates PDF where first line is 'Test text', and second contains image.
I need that text and image would be in single line like 'Test text [image]'.

Has anyone done this before?

I would like to get some advice on how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use columns

```
var dd = {
  content: [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          width: 'auto',
          text: 'Test text'
        },
        {
          width: '*',
          image: 'sampleImage.jpg', 
          width: 24, 
          height: 24
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it solves partially this issue. If text is long and it is wrapped in multiple lines than provided solution does not work so nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to be inline with your Multiline text you can use columns + stack

Example:

```
columns: [
 {
        image: "URL",
        height: 150,
        width: 180
 },

{
    stack: [
    {
        columns: [
          {
              text: 'First column first line',
              width: '35%'
          },

          {
               text: 'Second column first line',
               width: '35%'
          },

          {
               text: 'Third column first line',
               width: '30%'
          }
        ]
    },

    {
         columns: [
          {
               text: 'First column second line',
               width: '35%'
          },

          {
               text: 'Second column second line',
               width: '35%'
          },

          {
               text: 'Third column second line',
               width: '30%'
          }
        ]
    }
    ],
        width: '*'
 }]
```